# how to get digital out pins working correctly

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

this code works as expected except its not changing which led it turns on based on color. its always the middle orange LED that is on. any clue why?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <DHT.h>

#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN A0     // what pin we're connected to

#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11


LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (int DigitalPin = 7; DigitalPin <= 9; DigitalPin++) 
 {
  pinMode(DigitalPin, OUTPUT);
 }
  lcd.begin(16,2); //16 by 2 character display

dht.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1000);
  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Temp: ");
  lcd.print(t);
  lcd.print("'C");

  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Humid: ");
  lcd.print(h);
  lcd.print("%");

  if (t<=30)
  {
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  }
  else if (t>35)
  {
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  }
  else if (t>=45)
  {
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  } 

}
```

from what ive been reading and looking up it seems as if it should be working, but it is not. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I put the temp sensor inside of my raspberry pi case to make sure its not getting too warm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your if-else conditions like this:

```
  if (t<=30)
  {
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  }
  else if (t>=45)
  {
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

i think your error is on the second test

```
else if (t>35)
```

you have to change to

```
else if (t>35 && t < 45)
```

without this fix, a temperature of 50, the lamp will be orange and not red

but following your logic inside your program, you have forgotten the test between 30 and 35, or you have an error and change 30 to 35 or 35 to 30